# Need assistance combining jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hack together a couple of different jquery functions to help me complete a project I'm working on.

The first portion seems to work (Populating the two input text boxes, but I am unable to populate the second select drop down with the array I have provided. I am sure it is something simple but being new to jquery I cant quite figure it out.

**Edit**

I need to split the value of the options (Separated by the "_") of the first Select dropdown and send those to both of the text boxes displayed. This is important for my page's functionality.

Here is my html

```
<form action="/revenue_lines/lock" id="lockLockForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" id="RevenueLineDate1">
<input type="text" id="RevenueLineDate2">
<select id="selector">
    <option value="Data1_<Data1>">Sample1</option>
    <option value="Data2_<Data2>">Sample2</option>
</select>
<select id="item"></select>
```

And here is my jquery

```
$('#selector').on('change', function () {
var val = this.value;
var parts = val.split("_");
$('#RevenueLineDate1').val(parts[0]);
$('#RevenueLineDate2').val(parts[1]);
});

Sample1 = new Array('Top Story', 'Cases', 'News');
Sample2 = new Array('Top Story', 'Cases', 'News');

populateSelect();

$(function () {

$('#selector').change(function () {
    populateSelect();
});

});

function populateSelect() {
selector = $('#selector').val();
$('#item').html('');

eval(selector).forEach(function (t) {
    $('#item').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
});
}
```

Here is a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmill02s/deuq3/14/) I'm working off of.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deuq3/15/

Comment: This is close but I still need to split the values of the Options (separated by the "_") so I can populate both text boxes. Sorry for not being clear I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there!

Try this HTML instead:

```
<select id="selector">
    <option value="Sample1">Sample1</option>
    <option value="Sample2">Sample2</option>
</select>
```

Your .val() is getting the value attribute of the selected `<option>`, not the text.

**Edit:**

I see from your edit that the original values are important for you. In that case, replace your `.val()` in populateSelect with `.text()` and you'll get the behavior I think you want.

```
function populateSelect() {
    selector = $('#selector').text();
    $('#item').html('');

    eval(selector).forEach(function (t) {
        $('#item').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
    });
}
```

As a note, I wouldn't usually consider using the visible text that way a good practice - it prevents you from doing things like localizing the text. One alternative would be to instead key off of the first portion of the value (Data1, Data2) using `split()` and use those as your array names. Then you're free to change the displayed text without breaking your functionality.